# C# Check Condition With Duplicated ID and Different Name

Tags: c#

i would like confirm is my coding correct due i run it perfectly but it seems doesn't do a checking on the IC_NO which is unique number and different name. 
My point is i want to set the if statement if the IC_NO duplicate and different Name then it will out error.

```
if (!IC_No.Equals(var_name))
{
  var_return = false;

  LFC.writeTxtFile(var_LogFilePath, var_ErrorLogFilename + "_" + var_MinValue + "-" + var_MaxValue + ".log", "Error - The IC_No are duplicated for different name (Policy No: " + PolicyNo + ", Actual Age: " + ActualAge + ", IC_No: " + IC_No + ", Name: " + Name + ", DOB: " + var_Day + "/" + var_Month + "/" + var_Year + ")", true, true, false);
}
```

Comment: How do you like your code now?

Comment: im not sure im correct in terms of the format i wrote. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the names of the variables used in the `writeTxtFile` method, all I can gather is that you're missing part of the if statement... and a collection with your policies.

You need to keep track of all IC_No and names in a collection and then check if for a given IC_No there's an existing name already, something like this:

```
if (collectionOfPolicies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IC_No == this.IC_No && x.Name == this.Name) != null)
{
  // ...
}
```